# How to prove that if f is continuous that the exponential function satisfies the functional equation?

Tags: calculus, continuity

Prove that if   $f : \mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ is continuous with the property $f(x+y)=f(x)·f(y)$ for all $x,y \in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(1) = a > 0$, then $f(x) = e^x$.

I'd be greatfull for any help!

Comment: Your question title means something different from the text. The title asks to verify that $a^x$ is a solution, but "then $f(x)=a^x$" means you need to **disqualify** all functions except $a^x$ as solutions.

Comment: This question has appeared many many many times!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x)=f(0+x)=f(0)f(x)$ so $f(0)=1$ or $f(x)=0$. Since $f(1)>0$ the latter is denied.

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f(n)=f(1+\cdots+1)=f(1)^n=a^n$ by induction.

$1=f(0)=f(n-n)=f(n)f(-n)$ hence $f(-n)=f(n)^{-1}$.

$f(\frac{1}{n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n})=f(1)=a$ implies $f(\frac{1}{n})=a^{1/n}$.

Hence $f(\frac{m}{n})=a^{m/n}$.

Now, since $f$ is assumed to be continuous, one can continue to the conclusion that $f(x)=a^x$ by taking rational approximations $p_n\to x$, $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(p_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{p_n}=a^x$.

Comment: how does $f(1)=a$ deny the latter?

Comment: If $f(0)\ne1$ then $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, including $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much Chrystomath! It was really helpful! I now struggle with the second part of the proof where I need to show that e^

Comment: You cannot prove $f(x)=e^x$. For example, $2^{x+y}=2^x2^y$ is a valid possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can show inductively, that the statment holds on $\{ \frac{m}{2^n} | n,m\ \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ and this subset is dense.